# Facebook's Like button without Javascript?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to enable people with Javascript disabled to still be able to Like my content. I tried the following, but I cannot click the button:

```
<noscript><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http..."></iframe></noscript>
```

Comment: They are missing more than your like button without JavaScript...

Comment: It's good to be thinking about non-js users. However, have a look at the facebook website in a normal browser, with JS switched off. It is unusable. I think it is generally safe to accept that Desktop users who have facebook accounts, will have javascript switched on.

Answer (score 3):

You need javascript for it to work.  You can put an anchor (`<a href="...">Facebook</a>`) inside of the noscript though.

Comment: Can I allow people to Like my page through an URL?